# discord js how to check if message has a user id example: .ban [userid]

Tags: c#, discord, bots

discord js how to check if message has a user id example: .ban [userid]

example:
if (args[0] == userid)
{
this will be the user id function
}
else
{
This will be the user mention function
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to fetch the user id and check if it's a valid user:

```js
 // YOUR CODE

 // Assuming your Discord Client is named "client"
 let user = await client.users.fetch(args[0]).catch(() => null); // Fetch the user with the ID args[0]. If error -> output "null"

 if (user) {

  // Valid user id

 } else {

  // Invalid user id

 }
```

Make sure your function is asynchronous to use `await`.